# How to calculate the expression

Tags: math, modular-arithmetic

Given the equation-> (index+rotation)%rot=f;   if i konw the values of f , rotation , rot 
what is the formula to calculate index.I am not so good in mathematics but i want to know to calculate index in my programming.

Comment: `rot*k+f - rotation`, here k is a nonzero integer.

Answer (score 0):

> (index + rotation)%rot = f

means

```
index + rotation = rot*k + f, k is an integer (.., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2,..)
```

therefore

```
index = rot*k + f - rotation, k: integer
```

If you want to have `index > 0`, make sure to choose `k > (rotation - f) / rot`